Dynamic inheritance of type from within type?
I have following types example
Compile
interface Enforcer {
    name: string;
    keys: { [key: string]: number }
}
class Parent implements Enforcer {
    name = 'abc'
    keys = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        d: 4,
    }
}

const p = new Parent();

type Inherit<T extends Enforcer = Enforcer> = [T, (keyof T['keys'])[]];

const h: Inherit<Parent> = [p, ['']];

it works fine in which it auto-suggest and errors on h's array of keys, but I want to make it dynamic without the need to do const h: Inherit<Parent> = [p, ['']]; but instead just const h: Inherit = [p, ['']]; as p type is already clear.
I've also tried
type InheritK<T extends Enforcer = Enforcer, K extends keyof T['keys'] = keyof T['keys']> = [T, K[]];

const hk: InheritK = [p, ['']];

but no auto-suggestion and errors occurred.
I understand we can use a function but I would prefer if we can do it without the need for function calls.

No, it's a missing feature, see ms/TS#32794. You should use a function. See linked q/a for more info.

I think I have seen similar question in stackoverflow. however I am unable to find the link to that for reference. However, please try initializing with a helper function - create
function create<T extends Enforcer>(instance: T, keys: (keyof T['keys'])[]): Inherit<T> {
    return [instance, keys];
}

const h = create(p, ['a', 'b']);

Compile
